# My data doesn't show up on DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am currently learning SQL for one of my projects and the site, that I learn from, advised me to use DB Browser to see my Database Content. However, I can't see the data inside the SQL. This is how my code looks like. I'm creating a table and then trying to write some values in it. It creates the DB successfully but the data doesn't show up.

```
import sqlite3 as sql

connection = sql.connect("points.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers (server_id TEXT, name TEXT, exp INTEGER)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO servers VALUES ('848117357214040104', 'brknarsy', 20)")
```

[image: I'm also sure that they are in same directory]

[image: As you see table is just fine but the values are missing]

Comment: You need to call `connection.commit()` after you have inserted the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your data is inserted?

Something like this in the end:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM servers")
r = cursor.fetchall()

for i in r:
    print(r)
```

Perhaps SQLite browser just needs a refresh